# PLayframework redirect not working

Tags: java, playframework

I'am fairly new to Playframework and have some troubles redirecting to another template from clicking a href

**Routes**

```
GET     /                           controllers.Index.show
GET     /signin                     controllers.SignIn.show
GET     /signup                     controllers.SignUp.show
```

**index** *(view)*

```
<li>
  <a href="@controllers.Index.signOut()">
    Uitloggen
  </a>
</li>
```

**Index** *(controller)*

```
public static Result signOut() {
  return redirect(routes.SignIn.show());
}
```

**SignIn** *(controller)*

```
public static Result show() {
  return ok(signin.render("Inloggen"));
}
```

[image]

Also tried this:

```
public static Result signOut() {
  return SignIn.show();      // <-- call to SignIn (controller)
}
```

[image]

But whenever I user the route: /signin directly in my browser it works just fine..

What am I missing here?

Comment: why didn't you put '/signin ' for href??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route entry has the following structure:

```
[HTTP method] [url] [controller method]
```

The second column in the route file entry is the **url** to be used from a browser. When you provide the **url** to a browser, Play looks for the **url** value in the **route** file and calls a controller method.

Your Index is implemented like this:

```
public static Result signOut() {
   return redirect(routes.SignIn.show());
}
```

So, the controller method is **Index.signOut**.
Let's assign the url to it and add the entry into the routes file:

```
GET     /signout       controllers.Index.signOut
```

As soon as you will provide the url **/signout** to a browser, the redirection will take place.

By the way, SignUp controller, specified for the route /signup is missing in your example.

I also recommend you to remove static from the controller methods, if you do not have a special reason for it.

Comment: Hey thanks for response. It was not clear to me that each action actually needed his own route even when it just redirects to another route.
The reason why SignUp controller is missing is because the example isn't using it so I thought I could leave it out.
Thanks for helping me out here!!

Comment: Btw, by removing the static, I will get compiled errors: signOut is not a member of object controllers.Index

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<li>
  <a href="@routes.SignIn.show()">
    Uitloggen
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: This does work, but because of the sign out needs some more logic than only redirect it needs it own methode.